# How can I change color in UITextField when editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have UITextField with grey text "username", while this field aren't selecting by user . How can I change color to black, when user select this field and will begin type his username?
Sry my English

Answer (score 2):

I think you're approaching it the wrong way. From what I read i think that you need to go with "placeholder" text.
Open your xcode project, go to your .xib or .storyboard file, click on your `UITextField` and input 'username' on the `Placeholder` textfield, like the following image:
[image]

The `placeholder` text is a gray text that is displayed when your `UITextField` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `placeholder` property of UITextField for the grayed text that will be replaced with whatever user types in.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `placeHolder` text as "username" and it will be displayed in grey color then set the textColor of your textField as black color so when you will begin editing you will edit with blackcolor